# Import Using Bulk Insert with XML Format File and Codepage 65001

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulk, codepages

I am having difficulty importing a Unicoded fixed length files into SQL Server using Bulk Insert with an XML format file. The only way I can do it is to convert the file to ANSI and this loses the Unicode characters. Can anyone advise some code to import the file retaining the Unicode characters.

Row from the import file...
9999030000000007001Achsausführung                                              0

```
Bulk Insert LanguageDescriptionsTest from 'R:\SQLBackupsIncoming\TecDocDataDownload\Temp\030c.dat'
with
(
    firstrow = 1, lastrow = 1,
    codepage = 65001,
    formatfile = 'R:\SQLBackupsIncoming\TecDocDataDownload\LanguageDescriptions_FormatFileTest.xml'
)
```

XML Format File...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="22"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"/>  
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="9"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="60"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" LENGTH="1"/>


</RECORD>
<ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Reserved" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="22"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="DataSupplierNumberConstant" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="4"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="DataTableConstant" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="3"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="DescriptionNumber" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="9"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="LanguageNumber" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="3"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="Description" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="60"/>
 <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="EraseFlag" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="1"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: *having difficulty*... means what exactly?

Comment: What's the output of `select @@version` on your SQL Server? The `codepage = 65001` parameter is only supported on SQL Server 2016 and later.

Comment: Since you're wanting to insert Unicode characters (non-ANSI in this context, since technically all characters are represented in Unicode), instead of `xsi:type="CharFixed"` and `xsi:type="SQLCHAR"` have you tried `xsi:type="NCharFixed"` and `xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"` in your XML format file?

Comment: Having difficulty means I have tried all of the options I know or have read on stackoverflow and none work.

Comment: I have SQL Server version 15

Comment: Having difficulty means I have tried all the combinations of syntax I know and cannt get it ti import without errors.
I am using SQL Server version 15.
I have just tried xsi:type="NCharFixed" and xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" in my format file.  Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: `xsi:type="NCharFixed"` on all fields

Comment: Please add to your question output of the following statement: `select @@version;` There is no such thing as **SQL Server version 15**

Comment: I got this error with all fields set as xsi:type="NCharFixed"...
Attribute "TERMINATOR" could not be specified for this type

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5014356) - 15.0.2095.3 (X64)